# How to return pure html with Mvc JsonResult

Tags: android, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

In Asp.net MVC i want to return HTML in JSON so that i can access this html in android app.

```
public ActionResult GetContactText()
        {
            string str = "";
            CM cms = objcms.GetCMSData();
            if (cms != null)
            {
                str = cms.ContactUs;
            }
            return Json(str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

[Link](http://fmsnew.somee.com/Account/GetContactText)

In my database value is `"<p>Hare Krsna !</p>"` but when i see in browser or call it from other platform it returns

```
"\u003cp\u003eHare Krsna !\u003c/p\u003e\r\n"
```

this result. How to return pure html with Asp.net MVC 3.

Please Help!

Comment: How about using JsonResult instead of ActionResult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you inspected the str variable before it is returned to see if it is being html encoded before or in the Json() method?

You could use this, seeing as are you aren't wanting to return JSON objects anyway:

```
return Content(str, "text/html");
```

Json objects must begin with either "{" or "[", representing an object or an array.

If you need to have your return formatted as JSON then you will need to put the html within a string:

```
return Json(new { html = str }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And the returned JSON will look like:

```
{
    "html": "<div> content <div>"
}
```